# I have used Py2App to create an .app file from a Python code project I am working on but when I open the app to browse files they are all greyed out?

Tags: python, pandas, macos-catalina, py2app, .app

I have written an application using Python code utilizing the Pandas and Openpyxl modules.

Summary of my app:
Browse and find an excel file(original), browse and find another excel file(new).
Press a button and update certain columns from original file with information of new file using name of item as a reference. Press save button and save the file to my computer.

Using my Windows machine I have made it into an .exe file and everything works perfectly fine. I am able to do everything I created it to do. I am trying to make it compatible on both Windows and MacOS. I have created a .app file using Py2App, and the app "runs" just fine. I am able to browse for files and so far it looks like I am able to save files. The problem is that the files I am trying to "use" are completely greyed out and I am unable to choose any files. I'm fairly new to MacOS so any advice or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you show what you mean by grayed out?

Comment: https://www.bing.com/images/search?view=detailV2&ccid=LNu4UjPU&id=D26B5D5A6C00F97D0FCBAEC1AA62317462647843&thid=OIP.LNu4UjPUH_HqpRecKMt7nQHaF-&mediaurl=https%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNrpzW.png&cdnurl=https%3a%2f%2fth.bing.com%2fth%2fid%2fR.2cdbb85233d41ff1eaa5179c28cb7b9d%3frik%3dQ3hkYnQxYqrBrg%26pid%3dImgRaw%26r%3d0&exph=536&expw=664&q=files+greyed+out+on+mac&simid=608049511136643528&FORM=IRPRST&ck=F89C1FC65298F23A23A13B98B1999F5F&selectedIndex=85&ajaxhist=0&ajaxserp=0

Comment: "Not a text file", they all look like that, like every single file, not just the .xlsx files

Comment: Can you change the file format selector?

Comment: That's exactly what it was, lol. Thanks for the help!!! How do I mark this as SOLVED?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the file format selector.